# Cafaea pignerā est — the coffee is pledged?

Tags: translation-check, sentence-translation

I've tried to write a variation on 'alea iacta est' but for having given someone money on ko-fi, a website that styles their content creator donations as 'giving a coffee', hence the name 'ko-fi'.

Is 'Cafaea pignerā est' a close enough translation of 'the coffee is pledged'? I chose pledged due to the nature of the giving, otherwise it looks like ['dā'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/da#Latin), ['exhibē'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exhibe#Latin) or ['perhibā'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perhibe#Latin) would be more direct translations.

Comment: **pignerā** is the ablative of noun **pignus**. I think the perfect participle **pignerāta** (from verb **pignerō**) should be used here instead.

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian The long -a seems to be a mistake, since *pignus* is neuter. *pignera* (with a short -a) would be neuter nominative/accusative.

Comment: The three other suggestions linked by the OP are all imperatives. I take it he tried to find out what form *iacta* is, found the imperative *iactā* (from *iactare*, which is not the word Caesar used), and thought the form required an imperative.

Comment: @brianpck Oh, I had a senior moment when I wrote this comment. **pignerā** is indeed an ungrammatical form.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel that is exactly what I did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the verb form you need is the perfect participle (in the nominative singular feminine). This is also what *iacta* is in *alea iacta est*, the perfect participle of *iacere*. In your case that would be *pignerata*, making the whole sentence: *Cafaea pignerata est.* That would be grammatically correct.

However, it would only work if Ko-Fi were a pawn shop that lends you money and takes coffee as collateral – because that is the sense of the English verb “pledge” which *pignerare* covers. Secured lending is a perfectly common business model, but it's not what Ko-Fi does.

In fact, to the best of my knowledge, you do not *pledge* money on Ko-Fi, but *pay, send* or *donate* it. But the somewhat silly original idea of the website – and the reason you're bringing up the *potio Arabica* in the first place – is that you can ostensibly “buy someone a coffee” there. And while a literal translation might not really be idiomatic Latin, I would recommend to use the verb *emere* (to buy) here. It's a bit of a pun on a fixed slogan anyway.

The verb is *emo, emi, emptum*, so the form we need is *empta*, making the whole sentence: **Cafaea empta est** (the coffee has been bought).

If you insist on “pledge” (i.e., promise), I would use a verb which happens to be the Latin cognate of “promise,” *promittere*, which is often used for pledging money or other valuables: *Cafaea promissa est.* (For extra silliness, you could say *… sponsa est*; *spondere* also means “pledge,” but in a very solemn and sanctified way, while *promittere* is a more quotidian word.)